# answer converted to comment?

Tags: discussion, editing, moderation

so I've been away for a while, and may be behind in the news-on-the-scene, but I am unclear on the mod/administrative rationale for the activity on this question/answer:
[Is there any service like NordVPN but for residential IP?](https://superuser.com/questions/1623857/is-there-any-service-like-nordvpn-but-for-residential-ip#comment2478467_1623857)

it appears that the question was deleted and re-added as a comment?
Never seen that one before. is this new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were answering what is essentially a product recommendation question. The question should have been closed. It is also asking how to do it for a mobile device, another off topic reason.

Your answer was useful in itself but felt to me that it was not answering the question, the off topic product recommendation, as it was asked.

So I converted your answer to a comment.

Mods have a tool available to move commentary contained in answers to a comment. Most often it is used for new users who do not have the rep to comment.